# Different WIDGET margins on different phones with android 4.0-4.2?

Tags: android, widget, margins

I've small problem - I've and app (home screen widget) for android ICS and higher. But different phones with different OS version (4.0.4, 4.1.2, 4.2, etc) and also different brands (Samsung, HTC, LG, ...) makes my app look diferent.

Ok, it doesn't happens always, but on some phones just Android adds automatic margins to my own - and on some not!!! How is this possible, and how to avoid this? Looks like every brand does it in their own way - which is fine for them, but bad for me :)

EDIT:
I use dp, not px. The main problem is not in dp/px nor in portrait/landscape changes. Main problem is, that for example on phone1 my widget has NO margins (it's like sticked to screen borders) and on other phones it has automatic margins like it should. When I add my own margin to widget provider, it has this margins on phone 1, but on other phones it has (my margins + automatic margins). Hope, now it's clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, to close this answer - it looks like there is really no option to have same margin on all devices - as different devices uses different home screen implementation. I can't do anything with that...Closed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Reality show, when the Android it isn't platform independent, either Java it isn't.

For this reason a single android layout.xml should use elements which are doing layout acceptable in all targeted devices. The screen ratio differs, the dpi differs the resolution differs... As best practice:

use dp size instead of pixels
do different layout for portait and landscape case
have multiple folders based on screen size ( and different layout)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I use dp instead of px. The main problem is not in dp/px or in portrait/landscape changes. Main problem is, that for example on phone1 my widget has NO margins (it's like sticked to screen borders) and on other phones it has automatic margins like it should. When I add my own margin to widget provider, it has this margins on phone 1, but on other phones it has (my margins + automatic margins). Hope, now it's clear :)

Comment: it was clear, I have suggested to do multiple layout, in your case maybe need different ones by device. Theoretically not needed, but practically my clients want professional gui which look like the same at all devices, especially to look like as iphone...

Comment: exactly - layout by device. And that's what I don't want to do so I'm asking for a help :)) Because this is in my opinion issue which happens when every stupid manufacture wants to have their own "stupid logic and behaviour" of everything in android and then you have 100 devices with 20 different behaviours...

Comment: than write a mail to each Android manufacturer to change they OS and bring it to Standard ASAP, especially for Samsung and Motorola :)